# GPT 3.5 Turbo integration with Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions, openai-api

I am trying to integrate Dialogflow bot with new openai API GPT 3.5 Turbo in Node.js using google cloud functions. I have below code which throws error "finished with status code: 404". I have two other files as well. I tried with with text davinci 003 and it was working fine.
Can someone help?

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const {Configuration, OpenAIApi} = require("openai");
require("dotenv").config();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const textGeneration = async (prompt) => {
  try {
    const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      prompt: `Human: ${prompt}\nAI: `,
      messages: [
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
      ],
      temperature: 0.5,
      max_tokens: 100,
      top_p: 1,
      frequency_penalty: 0,
      presence_penalty: 0.6,
      stop: ["Human:", "AI:"],
    });
    return {
      status: 1,
      response: `${response.data.choices[0].message.content}`,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      status: 0,
      response: "",
    };
  }
};


const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    bodyParser.json({
      limit: "250mb",
    }),
),
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
      limit: "250mb",
      extended: true,
      parameterLimit: 250000,
    }),
),


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Path ${req.path} with Method ${req.method}`);
  next();
});


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});


app.get("/dialogflow", async (req, res) => {
  const action = req.body.queryResult.action;
  const queryText = req.body.queryResult.queryText;

  if (action === "input.unknown") {
    const result = await textGeneration(queryText);
    if (result.status == 1) {
      res.send(
          {
            fulfillmentText: result.response,
          },
      );
    } else {
      res.send(
          {
            fulfillmentText: `Sorry, I'm not able to help with that.`,
          },
      );
    }
  } else {
    res.send(
        {
          fulfillmentText: `No handler for the action ${action}.`,
        },
    );
  }
});

module.exports =app;
```

index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const app = require("./app");

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

server.js

```
const app = require("./app");
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I have been trying to solve this since 5 days ago. The solution that works for me to switch from `text-davinci-003` to `gpt-turbo` is the following:

```bash
npm i @maxijonson/gpt-turbo
```

```
import express from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import { Conversation } from '@maxijonson/gpt-turbo';
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

dotenv.config();


const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome to Genus SMART AI!'
  })
});

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const prompt = req.body.prompt;
    const conversation = new Conversation({
      apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
  });
  const response = await conversation.prompt(`${prompt}`);
    res.status(200).send({
      bot: response,
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).send(error || 'Something went wrong');
  }
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port http://localhost:${port}`));
```